# How to setup seperate Boost Test project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I want to use Boost Test to unit test my code in Visual Studio 2010. I've downloaded and built the latest version of the library.

I've read a lot on the subject here and elsewhere on the internet and people seem to suggest having a second project within your solution exlusively for your tests.

Fine, sounds good. I'm having trouble actually setting this up however. I've yet to find a clear explanation of the best way to set this up.

Do I need to use a Project Reference to make my unit test project reference my main project?
If so,  do I still need to add the Include & Source directories of my main project in the properties of my unit test project?  If so, what's the advantage of using the Project Reference in the first place?

Do I have to have my main project output a library for my unit test project to link in?  Again, I thought that Project References would make this unnecessary but it seems I don't really understand the Project References.

If at all possible could I get a very idiot proof, step by step procedure for setting up a Boost Test unit test project alongside a main project in VS2010?

Would I be better off going with the method laid out here (one project, different configurations to build tests or actual project exe):
http://blog.yastrebkov.com/2010/07/boost-test-setup-and-usage.html

Many thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no magic behind setting up a Boost.Test project. Maybe because it's a regular C++ (executable) project in no way different from a "normal" application. This is what I do:

1. Create a new C++ project. I always choose Win32 Executable with precompiled headers. I have a naming convention, that all test projects using Boost.Test start with "tests.boost.testee_name..."
2. In `"stdafx.h"`, add the include for `<boost/unit_test.hpp>` and define the `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` (I always choose the project name). Also, add all other includes for external components this project requires, e.g. other boost libraries, stl headers etc. This results in considerably faster compilation times.
3. The testee must be a library (dynamic or static). So "add reference" to all required dependencies. You can of course test header-only libraries, in that case do not add references.
4. Add source files to your test project, according to Boost.Test manual. The convention I enforce is one `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE` per file.
5. For convenience, I have a custom property sheet tailored for boost unit test, which I add to each boost test project. Among others it contains a post-build event, which runs the tests.

I have to add that, lately, I switched to MSTest with Visual Studio 2012 which allows a more comfortable way to manage the tests and test results. Nevertheless, for the most important parts of the software, I am still writing boost tests in order to ensure correctness with older toolsets and potentially other platforms.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: Project References simply ensures the build order of the projects correct? Making sure the library is built(if necessary) before the test project in this case. Setting up a reference does not take care of linking at all right? I still need to setup my test Project configuration to link with the library?

Comment: Yes and no. Adding a reference also takes case of linking.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  And the testee must be a library simply to facilitate linking it into the Boost Test project right?  If my end goal is to make an executable application I need a 3rd project that (with the main() ) that links with the library to make the executable, so:  library proj,  test proj & final exe proj.  Both test proj and final exe proj add references to  library proj and link it in?

Comment: (1). Yes. You should put the relevant parts of your application logic into libraries. Making them testable is just one good reason to do so. (2) Yes. In the default configuration, a boost.test project is an executable. It creates it's own entry point (main), so you don't need to (should not) create your own.